# How can I integrate MDX with STRAPI

Tags: next.js, strapi, mdxjs

I am creating a project in which I am trying to use [MDX](https://mdxjs.com/) with [STRAPI](https://strapi.io/) but I am confused. How and where to integrate that, as MDX work with .mdx file but as I am using strapi it works with API

Can anyone guide me throw this

Below is my Github link which contains STRAPI and NEXTJS projects

https://github.com/Yusufzai/strapi-blog-project.git

Answer (score 3):

I'm curious how this turned out. I'm considering using Strapi for a couple of projects, but I rely on MDX to inject components into my posts.

I'm currently using https://www.contentlayer.dev for handling my posts, but I do not like that I have to commit my posts to GitHub every time want to write. I'm looking for an easy and nice experience like a CMS. I have been using Contentful and Sanity for some time, but the developer experience is not the greatest in my opinion.

Comment: Could you please mention any updates or solutions you came up with?

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently using https://www.contentlayer.dev for my next.js blog's data too, hope someone could pointed out

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).